# Order wp_page_listging results postdate desc

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to list pages in one block by postdate desc. Now the code I have it is listing pages like this. exmp in case getpages 404,4012,414 - it is getting first all posts from 404 than all post from 4012 and than all from 414. That means if i have 8 posts 5 month ago in 404 and I'll write a new post today in 4012 ID , in the listing parent page it will be updated like first 8 posts from 404 ID and after my today's post with parent id  4012. Have you guys any idea how to merge results in whole one block and not one block separated on several blocks? Will be happy for every anwswer .THANKS

this is what I have. BTF it is a wordpress and it is page listings.

```
 <div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
    <?php $pages = array();
    foreach (array(404, 4012, 414) as $id) {
    $pages = array_merge($pages, get_pages(array('child_of' => $id ,'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' )));
    } ?>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
    <div class="thumb12wrap">
    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a>
    <div class="thumbwrapper88">
    <div class="shade23desc" ><a class="desc"  href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
    <a class="descarea"  href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"></a>
    </div>
    </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a standard `WP_Query`, and wrap the `<div>` around the whole thing?

```
<div class="thumb12wrap">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_parent__in' => array( 404, 4012, 414 ),
    );
    $pages = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $pages->have_posts() ) : foreach ($pages as $page): ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a>

    <?php endforeach; 
endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: because I'm totally noob in coding, just have wordpress theme downloaded a trying to modify it because I love design:S. Sorry it was not full code , I;ll update my question and maybe your answer needs some edits after my update. TAHNK YOU BRO!!!check it ^^